# Empty links in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I got my own created template in Wordpress. I got two pages : index.php and ab.php. My question is what should be a proper link code that links these two pages in menu? Because I always get 404 page or index.php page or blank. I try'ed everything including saving permalinks.

Here are a few of my examples:

```
http://example.com/?p=ab
http://example.com/?p=ab.php
<a href ="ab.php">
```

etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this is your first WP theme.
If that is the case I should tell that the hierarchy from pure php websites won't work. Check this https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/  WP uses the wp-admin part for creating new pages.

If you  are switching from php to WP, I think I can help a bit by giving few pointers.

If there is an issue with your project I can't quite get what is happening but if you call http://example.com/ab.php the php inside will run however it's not cool to reference pages that way in WP.